# Not able to sync data from QField

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

[image]

[image]

While packaging for QField, I had set the following QField layer properties

Cloud layer action: Offline editing
Cable action: Copy

Now I am not able to sync back data on my desktop(Image 1)
I am getting the error

> QFieldSync: The project you imported does not seem to be an offline project

Now that I have already collected lot of attribute data on my phone, the attribute data is also visible on my phone, how can I retrieve this data on desktop?